# Testing Python objects with complicated initialization

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, mocking

I find that I often want to have Python objects with complicated initialization:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, thing):
        self.complicated_processing_A(thing)
        self.complicated_processing_B(thing)
```

In my code, I then create the object and all the complicated processing is done:

```
f = Foo(thing)
```

This is great except that testing the `Foo` class is really annoying because you need to do a lot of mocking.

Another option is to change `__init__` so that it doesn't do much but then when I use the class, I need to carry out the extra steps:

```
f = Foo(thing)
f.complicated_processing_A(thing)
f.complicated_processing_B(thing)
```

Is there a good way to hide the details of a complicated class but also have clean testing code?

Comment: An optional argument that will do the complicated processing in constructor only if set to `True`? that also defaults to `True`?

Comment: @Chase, despite the simplicity, that seems like a worthy answer.  Nice out of the box solution.

Comment: Another option would be to mock the `complicated_processing` methods, in case you can't or don't want to change the tested code. If you can change the code, I would rather factor out all complicated initialization into one method that can be mocked away, instead of introducing an argument that is only used for testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose a class factory could be a good solution here:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, thing):
        self.thing = thing

    def complicated_processing_A(self):
        ...

    def complicated_processing_B(self):
        ...

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, thing):
        f = cls(thing)
        self.complicated_processing_A()
        self.complicated_processing_B()
        return f
```

In my code, I can do this:

```
f = Foo.create(thing)
```

and it is much easier to test all the pieces.